# Alternative to using INDIRECT in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

looking for an alternative to using `INDIRECT`

I have a Summary Page that lists only the Pricing and Cart Name from all the other sheets in the workbook that im using `VLookup` and `Indirect`

But i have 15,000+ cell that have the Indirect Formula and its causing the workbook to calculate very slow.

Here is an example of the workbook.

**Summary Page**
[image]

**Sheet To Pull Data From**
[image]

**Sheet To Pull Data From**
[image]

Comment: There is none. That is why workbook formats that relies on it are considered bad design. Good luck.

Comment: On the bright side, you can use as many OFFSET, NOW and TODAY functions as you like now without making much difference.